# Couchbase setting value

Tags: key, couchbase, setting

From my java code while storing into couchbase, to ensure that it is properly saved in couchbase used following code blocks.

```
OperationFuture< Boolean > result = couchClient.set(<key>,<value> );
        while( !result.isDone() ) {
            try {
               Thread.sleep( 5 );
            }catch( InterruptedException e ) {
                errorLog.error( "Error occurred while setting in couchbase " + e.getMessage() );
            }
    }
```

Checking with other whether there is any better way to ensure that object stored properly in couchbase.

Comment: That appears to be using the older (and end-of-life) 1.x Java client.  Best to move to the 2.x which is at 2.4.7 as of this writing.

Comment: Thanks. I will change library and try.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is what Couchbase calls Durability Requirements, which may be used on an operation like an .upsert() in the 2.x client.  This is covered in the [Couchbase Java documentation](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/document-operations.html) with a link to more info on the [concept](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/durability.html#concept_gyg_14s_zs).

Comment: Thanks.  I will go through those documents.